# Use html5 in asp.net mvc3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

I've tiked html5 Checkbox when creating asp.net mvc3 prject, I wated to use  tag but I couldn't access it. Also in Tools->Options->HTML->Validation->Target I found out the latest version HTML I have is 4.01
What should I do now? I need to use  tag.
Your answer is very helpful.
Thaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491) which, among other things, adds HTML 5 design-time support. Scott Gu also [blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/03/asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) about it:

[image]

Comment: Me too, I have installed it. And once I installed it I got all those new features. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: I dont know what was the problem but this link help me and it works perfect :)
http://www.raihaniqbal.net/blog/2010/08/html5-support-in-visual-studio-2010/